# Wrong symfony configuration

Tags: php, symfony, routes, namespaces, twig

I have a problem with configuration of my project and I can't see where is the mistake...

**AppKernel.php**
    ...

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            ...
            new CMS\CoreBundle\CMSCoreBundle(),
        ];
```

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
cms_core:
    resource: "@CMSCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

**src/CMS/CoreBundle/Resourcers/config/routing.yml**

```
cms_core_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CMSCoreBundle:Default:index }
```

**src/CMS/CoreBundle/Resources/views/index.html.twig**

```
{% extends "@CMSCoreBundle/template.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
test
{% endblock %}
```

**src/CMS/CoreBundle/Resources/views/template.html.twig**

```
{% block content %}
Template block
{% endblock %}
```

And I'm getting this message

> There are no registered paths for namespace "CMSCoreBundle" in CMSCoreBundle::index.html.twig at line 1.

Where is the mistake please ?
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 ways to fix it.

you can add your bundle to the path

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/CMS/CoreBundle/Resources/views/": CMSCoreBundle
```

Or try to extend your template like that

```
{% extends "CMSCoreBundle:template.html.twig" %}
```

I'm not 100% sure for the 2nd solution.

Hope it may helps you

Comment: I already tried the 2nd solution and it did not work. But the first one is right ! Thank you !